# What I am doing wrong in the below code for replacing null entries by desired text while doing hive import via sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username=retail_dba \
--password=cloudera \
--table departments_null \
--hive-home /user/hive/warehouse \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-table sqoop_import.departments_null \
--create-hive-table \
--outdir java_files \
--direct \
--null-string 'N/A' \
--null-non-string '-1' \
--fields-terminated-by '|' \
--lines-terminated-by '\n'  \
-m 1
```

The primary key has unique values whereas other column has NULL, but after import it is showing null only rather then N/A or -1, which I specified

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems fine.

Your hive table `sqoop_import.departments_null` is pre-created and not with `--fields-terminated-by '|'` and
`--lines-terminated-by '\n'`

Check create table script using

```
show create table sqoop_import.departments_null
```

**I think your field delimiter is causing issue here.**

Check data in HDFS directory corresponding to your table, it should have 'N/A' and -1 in it.